# Send server intern messages between http request and websocket

Tags: node.js, websocket

I have a microcontroller which sends data to an node js http server. I want to send a message to a web client through a websocket connection, when the microcontroller hits the http request.

This is my route:

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

router.route("/sendData").post(async (req, res) => {
   //some validation

   //Here I want to initiate a message which gets sent to a web client through a websocket 

   return res.status(200).json({ message: "sent data to server")};
});

module.exports = router;
```

Then i have a example websocket server:

```
import { WebSocketServer } from 'ws';

const wss = new WebSocketServer({ port: 8080 });

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
  //here i want to send a message to a client when the microcontroller hits the http request
  ws.send('data received');
});
```

Now, how can i create communication between the http-route and the websocket server? I am new to the handling of processes in node js. Do I need something like node-ipc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to get started with this is to:

1. Don't create 2 separate scripts, but combine both your express server and websocket server in 1 process. (You can still split up these 2 servers in multiple files, but the point is you want them both running from the same node instance).
2. Create a (global) [EventEmitter](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#class-eventemitter).
3. When a HTTP request comes in, you use this event emitter to `emit` some event.
4. The WebSocket uses `.on()` on the EventEmitter to subscribe to events. When they trigger, send the message back.
5. Make sure you call `.off()` when the websocket connection closes so you don't create memory leaks.